# Burninate [personal-website]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

No one even dared to make a wiki or an excerpt for the tag so I can't give you much information about the tag, but from what from I have picked up, [personal-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/personal-website) just means:

> (noun) A website about yourself

This certainly isn't productive in finding questions on stackoverflow and no one can be an expert in [personal-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/personal-website) creation. Three out of four questions on the tag are purely opinion-based, asking for help on what a "personal website" should use and can't be edited without removing the intent of the question itself.

---

With a total of four questions total (one is closed for opinion-based) and  **an average of one question *every other year***, I vote to burninate it the off-topic tag.

Comment: I approved your edit and removed the tag from two of the other questions as well as closing/editing as appropriate. I haven't dealt with the last one as it's a high voted question so the community thinks that it has some value. However, it will get dealt with fairly soon.

Comment: There's one question left in the tag and it has a lot of upvotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does seem to be an irrelevant tag, but for such a low number of questions I'd simply edit them yourself.

Given that you've got less than 2k reputation they'd have to be suggested edits so make sure that:

1. You fix anything else you can see wrong with the post.
2. You add a relevant comment as to *why* you're editing them.
3. Point to this meta question in the edit comment to show you asked and what you were told.

Assuming all the edits get approved that'll be be 8 points of reputation you'll earn!

If the questions are un-salvageable then:

1. Down-vote to make sure they get into negative scoring.
2. Vote (or flag) to close as "off topic -> opinion based" (or whatever's appropriate.
3. If the question has low views then *possibly* flag for moderator attention, but wait for your vote/flag to push the question into the review queues.

Once the question has been closed it becomes eligible for automatic deletion.

With such a low number of questions the likelihood of new questions being added to keep the tag alive is low.

Comment: The majority of the questions on the tag are just asking for help on how to make a personal website, which is opinion based and beyond editing. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin - in that case just flag to close as OT -> opinion based. If you down-vote as well, they'l be candidates for deletion once closed and the tag will disappear that way.

Answer (score 7):

I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7751172) the last post and the tag is now empty. It should be [auto-deleted soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112521/262861).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, and [this might be of use](http://i.giphy.com/24h54UjNdCZ7q.gif).